# Why would position:fixed make IE (8 or 10) crash?

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer

I have a very strange thing happening.  When I add position:fixed to a button and pull the page up in IE it crashes once I tab to that button.  It has the very help message "Internet Explorer has stopped working".  If I remove position:fixed from the button it all runs without problem.  I've done it on both IE 8 and IE 10, we don't have 9 or 11 on our computers at work.

Anyone have any idea why that happens and how I would stop it?

---

[Edited example, making it smaller.  It still gives me the same behavior]
Code example follows, the line I comment out is in the CSS section under #btnCheckLink.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <title>Crash Tester</title>
        <style>
            #content {
                position:fixed;
            }
            #btnCheckLink {
                position:fixed;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="content">
            <input type="text"/>
            <input id="btnCheckLink" type="button" value="Next">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's probably not position fixed that crashing your browser. Could be a combination of css and doctype that's making it crash. I have had this before and I had to remove css block by block to identify the issue. If you removed all css other than the position fixed part and it still crashes then you can start blaming it on that. And what is `if (true!=false)` what's the point of that?

Comment: The page is a jsp and true is the ouput of <%=boolVar%>.

Comment: In that case `if( <%=boolVar%> )` will suffice assuming boolVar returns a boolean

Comment: I have removed the extra css. I still get the same behavior with this modification.

Comment: Strange indeed, could have something to do with doc type. At this point for me at least, it comes down to trail and error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have two workarounds.  First, I have found that we have a group policy that defaults all intranet sites to use Compatibility View.  This is an intranet site.  Turning Compatibility View off stops the browser crash.  Hit F12 to open the dev panel and check IE's mode.

Also, wrapping the button in a div and using position:fixed on that rather than the button stops the crash.